# How to change the target directory of target-csv when running tap-target script inside python?

Tags: linux, bash, python, python3

I am trying to a script `run.sh` using python `subprocess`

The script creates a csv file and a state.json file in the `cwd`

This is the script(works fine when i run it from terminal) :

```
#!/bin/bash
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/anti/Documents/bq_s3/BQ/bin/client_secret.json"

/home/anti/Documents/bq_s3/BQ/bin/tap-bigquery -c /home/anti/Documents/bq_s3/BQ/bin/tap_config.json --catalog /home/anti/Documents/bq_s3/BQ/bin/catalog.json --start_datetime '2013-01-01T00:00:00Z' --end_datetime '2013-01-02T00:00:00Z' | /home/anti/Documents/bq_s3/targetcsv/targetcsv/bin/target-csv --config /home/anti/Documents/bq_s3/targetcsv/targetcsv/bin/target_config.json > /home/anti/Documents/bq_s3/state.json
```

But when i try to run the same from python, it shows the correct output , but doesnt create csv file and a state.json file at `cwd` .

Is there anyway to fix this ?

Here is my code :

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import subprocess   
from ast import literal_eval
import io
import os
from subprocess import call

shellscript = subprocess.Popen(["/home/anti/Documents/bq_s3/run.sh"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
shellscript.wait()
print (shellscript.returncode)
```